Geometry Optimization Problem
Consider the shape attached below:

The two points on the y-axis are fixed with coordinates, 5 and 10 respectively, and the point M can move freely along the x-axis.

The questions is: When is the angle between the two lines connecting M to the points maximized?

Obviously this can be solved by finding the tangent of the angle via trigonometry and solving an optimization problem corresponding to that, but my friend pointed out a theorem in Geometry that simplifies the solution brilliantly. I would love to know the proof of this theorem as he didn't seem to recall it, and to know where else there are uses for such mechanics using geometry.
Here goes his way of solving the problem:

First we reflect the point on the y-axis situated closest to the origin, across the x-axis, so B=(0,5) turns to B'=(0,-5), now consider this triangle AMB', according to said theorem, the original angle(AMB) is maximized when AMB' is a right triangle.
and then using some right triangle laws you can figure out that M's optimal coordinate on the x-axis is the geometric mean of the AO and B'O where O=(0,0) e.g. the origin so $\sqrt{5\cdot10}=5\sqrt{2}$, which adds up with the other method.

Now my question is: Why?

Please leave an elegant geometric explanation below.
My idea is that it includes some inscribing arc loci, and probably that famous reflection distance minimizing problem.
Thanks!

First of all we must observe that the angle is maximum if the circle through $ABM$ is tangent to the x-axis. Indeed, if it were not so, then we would be able to find a larger angle: angle $M'$ in figure below is greater than angle $E$ (by Euclid's exterior angle theorem), which is the same as angle $M$.

But if $OM$ is tangent to circle $ABM$, then we have $OM^2=OB\cdot OA$ (tangent–secant theorem), that is $OM^2=OB'\cdot OA$. But in a right triangle the altitude is the geometric mean of the two line segments it creates on the hypotenuse. Hence $\angle AMB'=90°$.


I thought at first it is coincidental, but having read the answer by Intelligenti Pauca, I have understood it is a general property.
The first part of this answer explains how the optimization constraint can be turned into a geometrical constraint.
The following figure displays the "pencil" of (arcs of) circles passing through points $A$ and $B$ restricted to the first quadrant.

Let us consider line segment $[AB]$ as the "scene" of a theater and the arc of circles as the stands (sitting places) of this theater : they have the subtended arc property : any person situated on a same  arc sees the scene under the same angle. The farthest you are, the smallest the angle. Therefore, as $M$ is constrained to be on the horizontal line, the best place $M$ has to be in is the point $M_0$ where a certain circle $C_0$ of the pencil is tangent to the $x$-axis.
Now, the second part of this answer is almost identical to the answer by Intelligenti Pauca.
The power of origin point $O$ with respect to $C_0$ can be computed in two ways :
$$OM^2=OA.OB=OA'.OB$$
But this relationship $h^2=a'b'$ in triangle $AMB'$ is a necessary and sufficient condition for having a right triangle (square of altitude $h$ issued from $M$ equal to the product of lengths of sub-segments $a'$ and $b'$ determined by this altitude on the opposite side).
Remark : An analytical solution for the position $M_0$ can be obtained by a specific computation.
Indeed, as the abscissa $c$ of $M$ and the abscissa of the center of this specific circle $C_0$ are identical.
Circle $C_0$ having $(c,15/2)$ as its center has the following equation :
$$x^2+y^2-2cx-15y+50=0\tag{1}$$
$C_0$ has a single point of intersection with line $y=0$. Therefore, setting $y=0$ in (1) we have a double root, which amounts to say that the discriminant of quadratic equation
$$x^2-2cx+50=0$$
i.e., $c^2-50$ is zero, giving the positive root $c=2 \sqrt{5}$ : we have retrieved the abscissa of $M$ you have computed.

Not strictly geometric explanation. A trigonometric explanation; but quite elegant.

We want to maximize $∠AMB$.

It's obvious it's always an acute angle, so we can as well maximize $sin (∠AMB)$ (as $sin$ is strictly increasing for acute angles).

$|AB|$ is fixed, so we can as well maximize $\frac {sin(∠AMB)}{|AB|}$.

From the law of sines (for the triangle $AMB$), then from the fact that $∠MAB=∠MAB'$ and $|MB|=|MB'|$, finally from the law of sines again (this time for the triangle $AMB'$) we get:
$$\frac {sin(∠AMB)}{|AB|}=\frac {sin(∠MAB)}{|MB|}=\frac {sin(∠MAB')}{|MB'|}=\frac {sin(∠AMB')}{|AB'|}$$

So we can as well maximize $\frac {sin(∠AMB')}{|AB'|}$.

$|AB'|$ is fixed, so we can as well maximize $sin(∠AMB')$.

By moving $M$ on the x-axis from $0$ to infinity we change $∠AMB'$ smoothly from 180° to 0° (in the limit), so $sin(∠AMB')$ changes from $0$ to $1$ and back to $0$ (in the limit). $1$ is the maximal value and it's achieved by $∠AMB'=90˚$.



Side note: we can convert $\frac {sin(∠AMB)}{|AB|}=\frac {sin(∠AMB')}{|AB'|}$ to $\frac {sin(∠AMB)}{sin(∠AMB')}=\frac {|AB|}{|AB'|}$ and in the optimized case where $sin(∠AMB')=1$, we get:
$$sin(∠AMB)=\frac {|AB|}{|AB'|}=\frac 1 3$$
